# How to make Geoserver dynamically calculate the bounding box of a postgis backed Layer

Tags: geoserver, extents, dynamic-layer

I set up a store for a postgis db.

I set up a layer that queries a table.

Geoserver requires that you set the Bounding Box of the layer when you create the layer.  The problem is that I don't know beforehand what the bounding box will be, since someone else will be writing on the table in the future.

Of course I could set a huge bounding box to cover all the expected points, but isn't it possible for Geoserver to compute the bounding box at runtime based on the actual data in the table?

Comment: No. Reason: GetCapabilities. You don't want to have to walk the whole database content every time some asks for which layers are available. Consider re-publishing the layers using the REST API if you have infrequent updates.

Answer (score 2):

Brad answer is spot on. However, there has been a desire to also allow admins to setup dynamic bounding boxes on selected layers, it just needs someone to implement it / sponsor it.

Comment: Was this feature ever implemented? I am in a similar position where geometry is dynamically added to GeoServer.